# What is the different between qcow2 format vs img format?

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I want to back up a virtual machine image when I went to the directory where the images are stored `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` I found one .img file, the rest were .qcow2, unlucky the virtual machine I want to back up is the one with the .qcow2 image. I'm not too sure what type of format that is also I'm not too sure if I compress this format if it would back up all of my data. Are you familiar with format, is my data stored in the .qcow2 file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To backup a qcow2, you have to quisece the filesystem (if it's running and `qemu-guest-agent` is running on the guest) and convert it to `raw`.

```
# qemu-img convert -O raw qcow2image.vm convertedraw.vm
```

When you want to restore it, you have to convert it back. Reverse order, changing the -O switch's value.

```
# qemu-img convert -O qcow2 convertedraw.vm qcow2image.vm
```

If the VM is running and you want to take a backup, these are the steps:

1. Freeze the vm.
2. Create a snapshot.
3. Thaw the guest.
4. Take a backup from the snapshot.

Like so.

```
# virsh domfsfreeze vmname
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b qcow2image.vm qcow2.snap
# virsh domfsthaw vmname
# qemu-img convert -O raw qcow2.snap backup.img
```